# XCode 7.1 stops compiling on a storyboard, Xcode 7.0.1 works

Tags: storyboard, xcode7

Have a project that was going fine.  Now, XCode 7.1 will not compile a storyboard 8.  I compiled the project with XCode 7.0.1 and it does not stop and seems to compile fine.

How do I trouble shoot this.  How do I find out what storyboard 8 is?